# issue with categorical variables and pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm doing this to read a csv file with pandas.

```
data = pd.read_csv(filename)
data.columns = ['column' + str(i) for i in xrange(1, num_columns)]
for cname in data.columns.values:
    c = pd.Categorical.from_array(data[cname])
    idx = c.levels
    data[cname] = idx.get_indexer(data[cname].values)
```

1. for some reason, the last element of the last column is always -1, even
   though the value exists.
2. the code above seems to skip one row

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `xrange(1, num_columns)` will return `num_columns - 1` columns only. So you would probably want to use  `xrange(1, num_columns+1)` instead.

Comment: hi, I'm setting num_columns to the number of columns +1 already